# CMD Batch Variable Won't Save FFprobe Output

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I have an CMD Batch Script that will convert a folder of mp4 videos to webm.

**You will need:**

- [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)/FFprobe installed and set in Environment Variables to run from CMD.
- A folder with an mp4 for FFprobe to parse.

---

To make it easy, this is only the first part of the script, showing the `Video Bitrate` variable.

Here is a full script, just replace the paths.
https://pastebin.com/raw/3ng77Exz

**How the Script works:**

- Loops through all videos in folder
- Has FFprobe parse the Video's Bitrate and save it to `%V` and
  `%vBitrate%`.
- Has FFmpeg use `%V`. Such as `-b:v %V` will become the parsed value
  `-b:v 9401k`.
- Converts each video from mp4 to webm using the parsed Bitrate

---

## Problem

I can't get FFprobe's Output to save to the variable. I've come up with a workaround, having it first save the bitrate value to a `temp file`, then import that to the `%vBitrate%` variable.

Example: `(%V > tmp_vBitrate) & SET /p vBitrate= < tmp_vBitrate`.

---

**Works**

Temp File Variable

```
cd "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\" && for %f in (*.mp4) do ffprobe -i "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Test\%~f" -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -v quiet -of csv="p=0" & for /f "tokens=*" %V in ("ffprobe -i "%~f" -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -v quiet -of csv=p=0") do (echo ) & (%V > tmp_vBitrate) & SET /p vBitrate= < tmp_vBitrate & del tmp_vBitrate & for /F %V in ('echo %vBitrate%') do (echo %V)
```

---

**Does Not Work**

Memory Variable

```
cd "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\" && for %f in (*.mp4) do ffprobe -i "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Test\%~f" -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -v quiet -of csv="p=0" & for /f "tokens=*" %V in ("ffprobe -i "%~f" -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -v quiet -of csv=p=0") do (echo ) & SET vBitrate=%V & for /F %V in ('echo %vBitrate%') do (echo %V)
```

---

**Testing It**

Run the first command. When it is finished, type `echo %vBitrate%` in CMD and press Enter. You'll see the bitrate of the last mp4 file parsed.

Do the same for the second command and you'll see it doesn't work.

---

## Solution

I would like to get rid of the `Temp File Variable` and get the second command to work.

`(%V > tmp_vBitrate) & SET /p vBitrate= < tmp_vBitrate` to just `SET vBitrate=%V`.

Maybe this whole thing can be simplified? Am I using the variables wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)... And what is `%V > tmp_vBitrate` supposed to do? I understand `%V` is an iterated file... Note that for `for` loop variables, you need to double the `%`-signs in batch files (like `%%V`)...

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] without refering to extenal sites.  Use a `for /f` to parse the output of a command see http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html Look through [frequent ffmpeg Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg?sort=frequent)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `ffprobe`, but I know `ffmpeg` dumps its file analysis to stderr.  Try adding `2^>^&1` to your `probe` command.

Comment: @rojo I used an FFprobe command that uses `2^>^&1` and it seems to work. I posted an answer with example script. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I solved this using different FFmpeg commands with `2^>^&1`.

Now it no longer uses a temporary file to set the variable.

**Video Bitrate**

```
for /F "delims=" %V in ('@ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~f" 2^>^&1') do (SET vBitrate=%V) & for /F %V in ('echo %vBitrate%') do (echo %V)
```

**Audio Bitrate**

```
for /F "delims=" %A in ('@ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~f" 2^>^&1') do (SET aBitrate=%A) & for /F %A in ('echo %aBitrate%') do (echo %A)
```

**Full Script**

Here is a full `batch script` that will convert `mp4` to `webm` and calculate and match the bitrates automatically using `video birate = (((size * 8) / 1000) / duration) * 1000`.

```
cd "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\" && for %f in (*.mp4) do (for /F "delims=" %S in ('@ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format^=size -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~f" 2^>^&1') do (SET size=%S) & for /F %S in ('echo %size%') do (echo %S) & for /F "delims=" %D in ('@ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format^=duration -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~f" 2^>^&1') do (SET duration=%D) & for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %R in ('echo %duration%') do (SET duration=%R) & for /F %D in ('echo %duration%') do (echo %D) & for /F "delims=" %V in ('@ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~f" 2^>^&1') do (SET vBitrate=%V) & for /F %V in ('echo %vBitrate%') do (echo %V) & (if %V EQU N/A (SET /a vBitrate=%S*8/1000/%D*1000) ELSE (echo Video Bitrate Detected)) & for /F %V in ('echo %vBitrate%') do (echo %V) & for /F "delims=" %A in ('@ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~f" 2^>^&1') do (echo) & SET aBitrate=%A & for /F %A in ('echo %aBitrate%') do (echo %A) & (IF %A EQU N/A (SET aBitrate=320000)) & for /F %A in ('echo %aBitrate%') do (echo %A) & (IF %A gtr 500000 (SET aBitrate=500000) ELSE (echo Bitrate within Vorbis Limit of 500k)) & for /F %A in ('echo %aBitrate%') do (echo %A) && ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\%~f" -vcodec libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v %V -pass 1 -acodec libvorbis -b:a %A -map 0:v:0? -map 0:a:0? -sn -map_metadata 0 -threads 8 "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\%~nf.webm" && ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\%~f" -vcodec libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v %V -pass 2 -acodec libvorbis -b:a %A -map 0:v:0? -map 0:a:0? -sn -map_metadata 0 -threads 8 "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\%~nf.webm")
```